# Proof of Fundamental theorem of calculus with $C^1$ using Divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

I was preparing for Mid sem exam.I was solving some last year question paper in that following question is there

prove fundamental theorem of calculus form Divergence theorem for $C^1$ function.
i.e f is continously differentible function then prove using divergence thoerem $\int_a^bf(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$

But How is this possible. Divergence theorem related to area and Volume where fundamental theorem is basic theorem which states as $\int_a^bf(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$

In proof of Divergence theorem, we are using fundamental theorem . But I have no idea even to start proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

I wanted to solve this problem Can any One give me some hint so that I can start this problem.